# Array in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a text view in which I want to display `NSArray *result` as text of the text view.

For eg:

```
result={@"home",@"Office",@"Park",@"Market",nil};
```

textView text should be:

> home
>   office
>   park
>   market

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i =0 ; i <[Array Count] ;i++)
{
  self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.textView.text, Array objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Correct any spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `componentsJoinedByString:` method, like this:

```
NSString *text = [result componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

You can use a different separator instead of `@" "`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop as such:

```
NSString *str =@"";

for (NSString *tmp in result) {
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",str,tmp];
}
```

If you want each entry on a new line replace the space with "\n".